# Change the opacity based on elements current offset

Tags: jquery, scroll, opacity, fade, offset

I try to set the `opacity` for some images, based on each current `offset`. The problem is, that the opacity is not equal to all images if you scroll far down.

That's what I try to accomplish, for **each** image:

```
################
#              #
#              #
#              #
#   === <= opacity 1
#              #
#   *** <= opacity 0.6
#              #
################

    ... <= opacity 0
```

Currently it works only for the first ~2-3 images. All further down are not set from `0-1`, rather than from `0.5-40` or else.

Another problem is, that if the scroll-offset is `0`, all images are hidden...

That's what I've done so far:

```
var $win = $(window);
var $img = $('img');

$win.on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();

    $img.each(function () {
        var $self = $(this);

        $self.css({
            opacity: scrollTop / $self.offset().top
        });
    });

}).scroll();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/c5SUC/0/

Any ideas how to get that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
var $win = $(window);
var $img = $('img');

$win.on('scroll', function () {
var scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();

$img.each(function () {
    var $self = $(this);
    var prev=$self.prev().offset();
    var pt=0;
    if(prev){
        pt=prev.top;        
    }
    $self.css({
        opacity: (scrollTop-pt)/ ($self.offset().top-pt)
    });
    console.log(scrollTop+" / "+$self.offset().top+"-"+pt);
});

}).scroll();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mQHEs/
EDIT

```
var $win = $(window);
var $img = $('img');

$win.on('scroll', function () {
var scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();

$img.each(function () {
    var $self = $(this);
    var prev=$self.prev().offset();
    if(prev){
        var pt=0;
        pt=prev.top;    
        $self.css({
            opacity: (scrollTop-pt)/ ($self.offset().top-pt)
        });
    }
    else{          //SHOW FIRST IMG
        $self.css({
            opacity: 1
        });
    }  
});

}).scroll();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mQHEs/1/

Comment: Great! However, the problem, that if the scroll-offset is at `0`, all images are hidden, still exists... :(

Comment: Okay, fiddled a bit around and it seems that it doesn't fade from `0%` to `50%`-scroll offset, than from `0%` to `100%`-scroll offset...