# Using Fade Scroll jQuery-effect on 2-column floated gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, opacity

http://jsfiddle.net/mQHEs/23/So I found this really neat jQuery, Fade scroll code here: [Change the opacity based on elements current offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327318/change-the-opacity-based-on-elements-current-offset).
However I noticed that this only works in one column. If one has two columns with floated items, only the items in the left column are effected by the function (See the jsfiddle).
Does anyone have a solution for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/mQHEs/23/

html:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/food/1" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/food/2" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/food/3" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/food/4" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/food/5" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/food/6" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/food/7" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/food/8" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/food/9" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/food/10" />
```

CSS:

```
img {width: auto; max-width: 50%; height: auto; float: left;}
img {display:block; margin: 10px auto}
```

JS:

```
    var $win = $(window);
var $img = $('img');

$win.scroll( function () {
    var scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();

    $img.each(function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        var prev=$self.prev().offset();
        if(prev){
            var pt=0;
            pt=prev.top;    
            $self.css({
                opacity: (scrollTop-pt)/ ($self.offset().top-pt)
            });
        }
        else{
            $self.css({
                opacity: 1
            });
        }  
    });

}).scroll();
```

Comment: The JSfiddle you linked does not have two columns of images

Comment: It works with two cols, see [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mQHEs/22/).

Comment: Sry, try this link istead: http://jsfiddle.net/mQHEs/23/
I need them all in one div, since it is a WordPress-blog I'm using this for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change
`var prev=$self.prev().offset();`
to
`var prev=$self.prev().prev().offset();`

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mQHEs/26/)